# How can I set and get the vertex color property?

Tags: customization, interface, vertex-colors

I can't find a way to display RGB values (or equivalent) without using the python shell.

I would like to get and set color values numerically (ie. not painting), I can't find it for weight painting either (I expected it to appear in the "n" panel with something like "vertex" as a title).

Comment: Are you asking how to get the RGB of a color in weight paint mode?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer ! Yes, I needed a way to edit or read the color's data of a vertex, thanks for the nice answer @zeffii , but I'm looking for something in the UI, without Python. At the UI level why is it at face level ?

Comment: i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 28):

> I would like to get and set color values numerically (ie. not painting),

There may be add-ons that cater to this, but at present (March 2016)

- Blender doesn't have a (non-Python) way to set the Vertex Colors per selected vertex/vertices. *Per face* is however, as stated below, not a problem.
- There is no built-in interface (yet) to get the rgb value of a selected Vertex. Each vertex can be shared by a number of faces, therefore a vertex doesn't necessarily have one color associated with it.  Behind the scenes the Vertex Colors are not stored in the data per vertex but in a Vertex Color layer, which stores vertex colors for each face of the mesh.

  Possibly this explains that a bit more clear. There are 9 verts in this subdivided plane, and the middle vertex is used in 4 faces and therefore has 4 different colors associated.
  [image]

#### Vertex Color Map

You can set a collection of faces to one colour in vertex paint mode, by selecting them and setting the colour from the colour picker, then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (while the mouse cursor is inside the viewport) will fill the selection with that colour. You can  enter numericals into the Blender colour picker.

You can pick faces with `face selection masking` [image]

If you want to do it by script:

```
import bpy
import random
 
# start in object mode
obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
mesh = obj.data

if not mesh.vertex_colors:
    mesh.vertex_colors.new()

"""
let us assume for sake of brevity that there is now 
a vertex color map called  'Col'    
"""

color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors["Col"]

# or you could avoid using the color_layer name
# color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors.active  

i = 0
for poly in mesh.polygons:
    for idx in poly.loop_indices:
        r, g, b = [random.random() for i in range(3)]
        color_layer.data[i].color = (r, g, b, 1.0)
        i += 1

# set to vertex paint mode to see the result
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')
```

Also a small blogpost about vertex colours [here](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.nl/2013/03/vertex-color-map.html) and [here](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.nl/2013/03/painting-vertex-color-map-using.html), if you are so inclined.

For `Weight Painting`, i'm not sure -- i'll let someone more familiar with that give an answer

Comment: How would you change this script to set the vertex colors equal to the value of the vertices themselves? I.e. each vertex RGB = XYZ?

Comment: How could I set the color to the value under the normal of a face or the approximate blended color if the vertices of that face are different?

Comment: @iKlsR using vertex_normals then, might be worth asking a separate question.

Comment: @iKlsR https://gist.github.com/zeffii/90399b67820dbf64628b vertex.normal

Comment: @zeffii The color _under_ the normal or the color in the middle of a polygon. I've never used vertex paint programmatically before so not even sure the api allows this.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by 'color under the normal'.. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6a74de7ea17a66b67c2f ?

Comment: best go for a new question, you will get some definitive answers - no doubt.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer... my question is about the GUI, not using Python. Vertex paint is vertex-based, right ? The face selection trick is almost ok, is there some way doing it per vertex as you can in Python ? I would expect it in edit mode, in some panel... but can't find it

Comment: Very helpful answer! If there is already a vertex color map that we want to keep, I figured out that we can modify the code as follows. 1. define a variable for the name: `vcol_map = "Something"` 2. Remove the conditional `if not mesh.vertex_colors:` and change the line below it to `mesh.vertex_colors.new(name = vcol_map)` (no indentation). 3. Define color_layer by the vcol_map variable instead of a name string: `color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors.get(vcol_map)` If the code is run a second time, the *Something* vertex color map gets renamed to *Something.001* and a new *Something* is created.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this code to apply color to vertices selected in edit mode:

```
import bpy

def color_to_vertices(color):
    mesh = bpy.context.active_object.data
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'VERTEX_PAINT')

    selected_verts = []
    for vert in mesh.vertices:
        if vert.select == True:
            selected_verts.append(vert)

    for polygon in mesh.polygons:
        for selected_vert in selected_verts:
            for i, index in enumerate(polygon.vertices):
                if selected_vert.index == index:
                    loop_index = polygon.loop_indices[i]
                    mesh.vertex_colors.active.data[loop_index].color = color

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

import random

RGB = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(3)]
color_to_vertices(RGB)
```

The result will be like this:

[image]

Don't forget about proper material node setup if you want to see the result in edit mode (material viewport shading) and render:

[image]

For convenience sake you maybe want to create some panel and an operator.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this all day and I finally got somewhere with my plugin!

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be working with .ply files (or can convert your model to that), I recommend using the [Point Cloud Visualizer](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uhlik/bpy/master/space_view3d_point_cloud_visualizer.py), like so:

```py
from space_view3d_point_cloud_visualizer import PlyPointCloudReader

ply_filename = "some_file.ply"
point_cloud = PlyPointCloudReader(ply_filename).points

# get color of point at index 100
red = point_cloud['red'][100]
blue = point_cloud['blue'][100]
green = point_cloud['green'][100]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update for 4.0 and the new [Attribute](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Attribute.html#bpy.types.Attribute) API.

**IN OBJECT MODE**

```
import bpy
import random

obj = bpy.context.active_object
if obj.type == 'MESH':
    mesh = obj.data

    point_color_attribute = mesh.color_attributes.get("MyPointColors") or mesh.color_attributes.new(name="MyPointColors", type="BYTE_COLOR", domain="POINT")
    point_colors = [None] * len(mesh.vertices) * 4
    point_color_attribute.data.foreach_get("color_srgb", point_colors)  # Get Point Colors
    print(point_colors)

    for _ in range(len(mesh.vertices)):
        point_colors.extend((random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 1))
    point_color_attribute.data.foreach_set("color_srgb", point_colors)  # Set Point Colors
    print(point_colors)

    corner_color_attribute = mesh.color_attributes.get("MyCornerColors") or mesh.color_attributes.new(name="MyCornerColors", type="BYTE_COLOR", domain="CORNER")
    corner_colors = [None] * len(mesh.loops) * 4
    point_color_attribute.data.foreach_get("color_srgb", corner_colors)  # Get Corner Colors
    print(corner_colors)

    for _ in range(len(mesh.loops)):
        corner_colors.extend((random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 1))
    corner_color_attribute.data.foreach_set("color_srgb", corner_colors)  # Set Corner Colors
    print(corner_colors)
```

**IN EDIT MODE**

In edit mode the regular way to access attributes yields empty sequences. You have to use the [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html#module-bmesh) construct.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import random

obj = bpy.context.active_object
if obj.type == 'MESH':
    mesh = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

    point_color_attribute = mesh.color_attributes.get("MyPointColors") or mesh.color_attributes.new(name="MyPointColors", type="BYTE_COLOR", domain="POINT")
    point_color_layer = bm.verts.layers.color[point_color_attribute.name]
    point_colors = []
    for vert in bm.verts:
        point_colors.extend(vert[point_color_layer])  # Get Point Colors
    print(point_colors)

    point_colors = []
    for vert in bm.verts:
        vert[point_color_layer] = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 1)  # Set Point Colors

    corner_color_attribute = mesh.color_attributes.get("MyCornerColors") or mesh.color_attributes.new(name="MyCornerColors", type="BYTE_COLOR", domain="CORNER")
    corner_color_layer = bm.loops.layers.color[corner_color_attribute.name]
    corner_colors = []
    for face in bm.faces:
        for loop in face.loops:
            corner_colors.extend(loop[corner_color_layer])  # Get Corner Colors
    print(corner_colors)

    for face in bm.faces:
        for loop in face.loops:
            loop[corner_color_layer] = (random.random(), random.random(), random.random(), 1)  # Set Corner Colors
            
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```