# Python - get RGB value from face with generated texture

Tags: python, scripting

I just began learning Blender Python API, not sure if what I am asking is possible. I want to write a script to distribute objects on the surface of a mesh based on RGB value of a generated texture. Similar or identical to the way Blender already does it with particles emission. To do that, I assume I need to have a way to get RGB value at all the points on the faces of the mesh.

If that fails, what about just the vertices colors?

Comment: Not aware of a way to read the color value at a surface point directly (wish I did - if anyone does please lemme know! looking for this for a while). However you can bake from blender internal to vertex colors (not so in cycles as far as I know), and reading vertex colors in Python is fairly simple (if not entirely straightforward) as you can easily find here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/909/how-can-i-set-and-get-the-vertex-color-property/911#911

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! Hopefully someone can answer our question..