# convert xyz to uv and set texture color from python

Tags: python, mesh, texturing, uv

How can I transform XYZ locations into UV coordinates for a mesh?  I have a mesh and a data that consists of temperatures at various XYZ values on the surface of the mesh (not vertex locations).  I want to generate a texture of this data and apply it to the mesh.

I can call bpy.ops.uv.smart_project() on the mesh to generate UV coordinates for the mesh.  What I haven't found is a way to map XYZ values into UV, or set a pixel value of a texture once I have the UV coordinates.

Comment: You might want to use *vertex colors* for that (see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/911/3710)). If that's an option, I suggest have a look into the [specifications of a `.ply` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)) to write your own files with vertex colors and import them [as usual](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.import_mesh.html?highlight=import_mesh%20ply#bpy.ops.import_mesh.ply). Otherwise please share some example files to play with. It's hard to help, based on your provided informations.

Comment: The problem with vertex colors is that they require modifying the mesh.  I can't afford a vertex per pixel. This is also not a 1-off for a video, but a visualization that will be rendered many times and ways.