# Is there a Blender api to fill a color to a certain vertex_colors?

Tags: python, vertex-colors

Taking a cue from [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/909/how-can-i-set-and-get-the-vertex-color-property/911#911), I'm testing to make a one-color fill to a vertex_colors.
Works fine, but is very slow on meshes with many polygons.

```
ob = context.object
color = (0,0,0,0)
vertex_color = ob.data.vertex_colors['My Vertex color']
            
i = 0
for p in ob.data.polygons:
    for idx in p.loop_indices:
        vertex_color.data[i].color = (color)
        i += 1
```

I also found an operator,`bpy.ops.paint.vertex_color_set()` (It seems to be twice as fast)
but I don't really like the idea, plus it's an operator with no input apparently

Is there any blender Api that do this directly?

**After a good answer:**

The code above is code that doesn't make sense in this case.
My tests moved to this method (Not very fast):

```
for d in vertex_color.data[:]: #Slow method
    d.color = (1,0,0,1)
```

In any case, given @batFINGER answer, and @lemon help, the code is now 4 times and more, faster than before.

Comment: You can use "o.data.vertex_colors['Col'].data.foreach_set( "color", colors )" where "colors" is a flatten array of all the rgba colors.

Comment: Sorry @lemon RuntimeError: internal error setting the array

Comment: the array needs to be flatten: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...] not [(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), ...] and its length is so each vertex is considered for each face it belongs to. So for the cube, there are 24 vcols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Set all loop vertex colors to one**

Use foreach set method. Example of use here creating bezier curves https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/180184/15543

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

context = bpy.context

name = "Xxxx"
r, g, b, a = (1, 0, 0, 1) # red


ob = context.object
me = ob.data

color_layer = (me.vertex_colors.get(name)
               or me.vertex_colors.new(name=name)
               )
ones = np.ones(len(color_layer.data))

color_layer.data.foreach_set(
        "color",
        np.array((r * ones, g * ones, b * ones, a * ones)).T.ravel(),
        )
        
me.update()
```

Could also simply

```
np.array((r, g, b, a) * len(color_layer.data)).T.ravel()
```