# Vertex Paint For Multiple Objects in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, modifiers

How can I set my favorite color to all of the selected objects?

I can't attach my objects not at all.

The number of objects is high and I can not adjust their color vertex one by one.

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/909/how-can-i-set-and-get-the-vertex-color-property) is for vertex color of single object
[image]

I converted it to multiple objects:

```
import bpy
import random
import time
# start in object mode
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
for obj in objects:
    
    mesh = obj.data

    if not mesh.vertex_colors:
        mesh.vertex_colors.new()


    color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors["Col"]

    # or you could avoid using the color_layer name
    # color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors.active  

    i = 0
    for poly in mesh.polygons:
        for idx in poly.loop_indices:
            color_layer.data[i].color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
            i += 1
    # set to vertex paint mode to see the result
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')
```

Comment: Hello Seyed, I'm trying to use your script and keep getting this error with not much happening-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\3D\Jen_n_Tim\ShatteredMoon\ShatteredMoon_V2.Bake.blend\Text", line 10, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'vertex_colors'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Any ideas, or does it not work in Blender 2.92?
I tried with both mesh.vertex_colors.new() and mesh.vertex_colors.active
same result.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from Seyed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192730/150021) changes the vertex color of all scene objects. This script changes **only the selected objects**:

```
import bpy
import random
import time

# start in object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# get selected objects
objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in objects:
    
    mesh = obj.data

    if not mesh.vertex_colors:
        mesh.vertex_colors.new()


    color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors["Col"]

    # or you could avoid using the color_layer name
    # color_layer = mesh.vertex_colors.active  

    i = 0
    for poly in mesh.polygons:
        for idx in poly.loop_indices:
            color_layer.data[i].color = (1, 0, 1, 1)
            i += 1

    # set to vertex paint mode to see the result
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')
```