# How to interpolate vertex colors in a cube?

Tags: vertices, color, vertex-colors, interpolation

I have this model made out of cubes:
[image: voxel cube structure]

And I want to set the white cube some vertex colors, which correspond to the vertex's surrounding cube/cubes and interpolate between them. Note that this cube must be geometrically perfect, thus I don't want to be using any brushes or tools where I must draw freehand.

Is there any simple way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - each vertex is usually used to store only one color. In your example one vertex consists from three colors. So the only one way to interpolate is to set average color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vertex Colors are actually 'Face-Vertex' colors  see: eg. [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/911/35559), stored in face-loops, like UV's,  so there can be more than one color per vertex.

Comment: @Vklidu Thanks, in my example I was using materials for the other cubes colors, is it better to only use vertex colors in an instance like this?

Comment: As mentioned in my A - I'm not sure what exact result are you expecting (some image could help) for the same reason I don't know if this is better than something else. Also I have to go study @RobinBetts comment that confused me :) thanks for that Robin. so probably Robin can answer deeper your Q.

Comment: Would need more context, how @Maxim wants the original colors to be assigned, how general the solution needs to be, etc? But it looks that your answer is fine..:)