# How to color or overlay on vertices via the Python api?

Tags: python, scripting, vertex-colors, development, custom-attributes

For a plugin I am making, I need to highlight the vertices that the user hovers over. I could not work out this color assignment part yet. I have tried methods then found out they were obsolete. I have tried color attributes but it didnt seem to do anything.. Heres the code anyways:

```
import bpy
import random

obj = bpy.context.active_object
if obj.type == 'MESH':
    mesh = obj.data
    # Get the active color layer
    color_layer = mesh.color_attributes.active  

    # Create a new layer if none exists
    if not color_layer:
        color_layer = mesh.color_attributes.new(name="FalloffGradient", type="FLOAT_COLOR", domain="POINT")
    
    colors = []
    # Example: Set random colors for each vertex
    for v in mesh.vertices:
        colors.append({'index':v.index,'color':(random.random(), random.random(), random.random()),'alpha':1.0})
    
    color_layer.data.foreach_set("colors",colors) # I think this is wrong since i didnt set the size first
    
    # Ensure changes are reflected in the viewport
    mesh.update()
    
    # If vertex colors aren't visible by default:
    obj.data.use_paint_mask_vertex = True
```

I feel this is the wrong way to do things. Would really appreciate this or any other solutions that make highlighting possible, including opacity.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set and get the vertex color property?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308346/86891)

Comment: It was about an overlay or color over specific vertices, namely hovered ones, this solution is a complicated workaround. I thought it was possible to edit the orange/white colors that blender has for default selections